# Filter Dictionary from list in vb.net

Tags: vb.net-2010

I got stuck up with the problem that I have a Dictionary (dictData [String,XElement]) and a list (lstData [String]).

So now I want to filter the dictionary with all the elements in dictionary Key other than list items. 
So basically compare list (lstData) items with dictionary keys (dictData) and if any list element exists in dictionay remove it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

> foreach (var key in MyDictionary.Keys.Except(lstData).ToList())
>
> {
>
> ```
> MyDictionary.Remove(key);
> ```
>
> }

But in VB?

Use **Except** if you want to exclude from your dictionary the item that are not in the list, use **Intersect** if you want to excluse those in the list.

Don't forget "using System.Linq;"